# CORSMiddleware not adding Access-Control headers

Tags: go, cors, http-headers, go-gin

I have added this code in my service but the server is not sending Access-Control headers, am I doing something wrong, I've attached a screenshot of all the response headers I'm getting.

```
func CORSMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PATCH, PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, X-Custom-Header, Content-Type, Content-Template, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, accept, origin, Cache-Control, X-Requested-With")

        log.Infof(c, "All headers %v", c.Writer.Header())
        log.Infof(c, "All headers %v", c.Request.Header)

        if c.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" {
            c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusNoContent)
            return
        }

        c.Next()
    }
}
```

```
router := gin.Default()
router.Use(gin.Recovery())
router.Use(middlewares.CORSMiddleware())
router.Use(middlewares.AuthMiddleware())
```

How can I solve this issue, one more thing, the response status code is 301 and the method type is OPTIONS, I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Rather than re-implementing CORS yourself (which is error-prone), you should use [Gin's CORS middleware](https://github.com/gin-contrib/cors).

Comment: This didn't help me, my frontend was adding a trailing slash in the URL's and I was getting CORS error because of that.